# standard errors in R psoptim

Tags: r, optimization

I am working on estimating a non-linear function. I am using the  optim and Rsolonp packages to do so and I am able to obtain the standard errors of my estimated parameters by using the Hessian that these functions calculate. As my problem seems to be  a  quite non-smooth one I found out that I can use the psoptim package. Nevertheless, I cannot figure out how I can obtain a Hessian using this package. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing this the hard way. Have you tried `nlsLM(...)` in package `minpack.lm`. It produces objects of class `nls` which have a `summmary(...)` method the returns the std errors in the coefficients directly.

Comment: Incidentally, using parameter std errors to calculate, e.g. confidence limits is not a legitimate technique with non-linear regression (although it's often used...). The `confint.nls(...)` method does this the correct way.